# Incorrect syntax near UserRegd error is coming

Tags: c#, sql-server

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=bpnaidu-pc\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=Userlog;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False");
con.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INT0 UserRegd values('" + ddl_signup.Text + "','" + txt_user.Text + "','" + txtEmail1.Text + "','" + txtPassword.Text + "','" + txtConPassword.Text + "')", con);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: Indeed - be grateful to the typo, as it's prevented you from actually having a security vulnerability at the moment...

Answer (score 2):

Replace Zero with `O` in your query.

```
INSERT INT0
```

should  be

```
INSERT INTO
```

And don't forgot about dangerous SQL Injection. Use *paramertized* query.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO UserRegd values(@signUp,@user,@email,@password,@confirmPassword)", con);

cmd.Parameters.Add("@signUp", ddl_signup.Text);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@user", txt_user.Text);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@email", txtEmail1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@password", txtPassword.Text);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@confirmPassword", txtConPassword.Text);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Answer (score 1):

You are typing `0` instead of `O`

```
INSERT INT0 <--- here
```

Change it to:

```
INSERT INTO
```

Also you should consider using [*parameterized queries*](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter) to prevent `SQL Injection` attacks.

Comment: Yes this answer is working(0----O)

Answer (score 1):

`INT0` should be `INTO`, you have digit zero at the end.

Use [Parameterized query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Your current query is susceptible to [SQL Injeciton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), Something like:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=bpnaidu-pc\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=Userlog;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False"))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO UserRegd values(@signup, @user, @email, @password)", con))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@signup", ddl_signup.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", txt_user.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", txtEmail1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtPassword.Text);
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What is `0` ?

You should use `INSERT INTO`

```
0------>o
```

Answer (score 0):

`INSERT INT0` should be `INSERT INTO`

Also please don't build a parameterized query with string concatenation. Use [`SqlParameter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead.